# Set directory for xna StorageDevice on windows

Tags: xna

I am using [easystorage](http://easystorage.codeplex.com/) framework to save my game data on Xbox360 and Windows. It works fine, but on Windows it seems to be hardcoded to save data in `MyDocuments`. After looking sourcecode of easystorage framework, i have found that the problem is undelaying Microsoft class [StorageDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.storagedevice.aspx).

> Implementation on Windows
>
> User storage is in the My Documents folder of the user who is
>   currently logged in, in the SavedGames folder. A subfolder is created
>   for each game according to the titleName passed to the
>   BeginOpenContainer method. When no PlayerIndex is specified, content
>   is saved in the AllPlayers folder. When a PlayerIndex is specified,
>   the content is saved in the Player1, Player2, Player3, or Player4
>   folder, depending on which PlayerIndex was passed to
>   BeginShowSelector.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200105.aspx

So my question is: Can i somehow reconfigure [StorageDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.storagedevice.aspx) or [StorageContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.storagecontainer.aspx) classes on Windows so, that my saved data will be saved for example in %appdata%?

Comment: At a quick glance over the MSDN pages related to StorageDevice and other XNA Storage classes I couldn't find anything that would allow you to change the default save location.  I believe this is because XNA relied on Games for Windows Live (GFWL) which has recently shutdown. GFWL would save the users data in an folder within the users documents. What I would recommend if you really want to have the data save in the user's AppData would be to write your own save system using the System.IO namespace.

Comment: @Loothelion yes, i supose it is done intendently because installers often locate games in ProgramFiles and you can not write to ProgramFiles without admin rights. But actually now the common place for savegames ist %appdata%, not MyDocuments. Actually many users dont like if somebody writes in MyDocuments. So a little hack for StorageDivice would be nice for me. Otherwise i must write and support 2 code paths fow WIN(system.io) and XBOX (easystorage xna framework).